Axios vs inertia useForm in laravel + inertia + vue
In laravel with vue as frontend using inertia, which approach is better for sending form data to backend; axios or methods provided by ineria ? Also, do I need to validate the from on client side (using library like vee-validate) in case I'm using inertia ?
const response = await axios.post(url, formData)
gives more flexibiliy, but
form = useForm(formData); 
form.post(url)

is simple, and has some good properties and methods like form.errors, form.processing, form.transform() etc.
